# jQuery hover handler function not working on unhover after dynamically adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

From my research i believe that the following code should work.

I am dynamically adding images to a page using jquery, which pulls these images from a JSON file. For this reason I need to use jQuery's [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to allow this hover to work.

I am following the guidance in the jquery docs -- [see here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1).

```
$(document).on('hover', ".portrait-image", function() {
    console.log('hi');
}, function () {
    console.log('bye');
});
```

This code repeatedly shows `bye` while never logging `hi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover` is not an event you can use with `on`. It is only a shorthand for the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. So you have to use them with the correct names for your delegation.

As from the documentation:

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.

So rewrite your listener like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.portrait-image', function() {
    console.log('hi');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.portrait-image', function() {
    console.log('bye');
});
```

Or like this:

```
$(document).on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        console.log('hi');
    },
    'mouseleave' function() {
        console.log('bye');
    }
}, '.portrait-image');
```

---

**To explain why only `bye` is shown:**

Like seen in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), `on` has up to four parameters. The last two are `data` and `handler`. Your `hi` callback is interpreted as `data` and will be ignored. The `handler` is the actual `bye` callback for the handler.

`hover` is a pseudo name in jQuery. It will do something like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.portrait-image', function() {
    console.log('hi');
});
```

This means every time you `enter` OR `leave`, it will print `bye`.

Comment: @VisioN it is definitely logging `'bye'`

Comment: Also, do you know that delegated events can be grouped? For example: `$(document).on({ mouseenter: ..., mouseleave: ... }, '.portrait-image')`.

Comment: See my edited answer @phantom!

Comment: @DavidR, this example is wrong. Please read the question again.

Comment: @VisioN, yes I know this notation. But I don't like this style. But to be complete I've added it ... Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, @phantom!